# При отправке формы на сайте не отправляется id user'а. Django

Tags: python, django

Помогите с проблемой
**ОШИБКА:  значение NULL в столбце "user_id" отношения "todos_category" нарушает ограничение NOT NULL
DETAIL:  Ошибочная строка содержит (11, asd, asd, null).**
forms.py:

```
class CategoryCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = [
            'name',
            'description',
            ]
```

В fields засунуть user_id я не могу, так как user_id должен автоматически добавляться в форму в зависимости от нынешнего юзера.. Вот только как это сделать я не очень понимаю.
views.py:

```
def category_create(request):
    form = CategoryCreateForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CategoryCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("category_list")
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'todolist/category_create.html', context)
```

models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

null=True в поле я ставить не могу((

Comment: можете передавать `Category(user=request.user)` в параметр `instance` формы при ее создании.

Comment: Попробую, спасибо

Comment: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
Появляется это ошибка теперь при обычной загрузки страницы с формой

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то нужно instance передавать во views.py в CategoryCreateForm?

Comment: ок, тогда какого пользователя хотите передавать?

Comment: просто если вы получили AnonimousUser то значит вы не авторизованы

Comment: Я авторизован через Django Oauth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тогда попробуйте так

```
def category_create(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        raise Exception('AUTH PLEASE')

    form = CategoryCreateForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CategoryCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            return redirect("category_list")
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'todolist/category_create.html', context)
```

Если будет исключение 'AUTH_PLEASE' то надо разбираться с вашей авторизацией

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался))